Kubernetes pods crash only if I attach a Persistent Volume on EFS
I'm trying to deploy postgres with persistent storage on Kubernetes. I'm using EFS and EKS and I configured the storage class on EFS.
If I try to create a PVC by itself it does go into the "Bound" state and everything seems fine.
If I try to attach a PVC to a Pod it won't start and it doesn't even give an error message. It just goes into CrashLoopBackOff state and doesn't start.
Here is the deployment.yaml file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak-deployment
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: keycloak
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: postgres
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# If I cut off the file here the pod runs fine, but without persistent storage.
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-keycloak-pvc
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-keycloak-pvc
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: postgres-keycloak-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

Here is the PVC of the deployment:
NAME                    STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   VOLUMEATTRIBUTESCLASS   AGE
postgres-keycloak-pvc   Bound    pvc-4fe11950-07f3-4af4-aa8f-f9e6b0fdb413   1Gi        RWX            efs-sc         <unset>                 8s

Here is the result of the describe command on the pod with persistent storage:
Name:             keycloak-deployment-85d769f687-rfqbq
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Start Time:       Wed, 06 Nov 2024 08:45:17 +0000
Labels:           app=postgres
                  pod-template-hash=85d769f687
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               xxxxxxxxxx
IPs:
  IP:           xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/keycloak-deployment-85d769f687
Containers:
  postgres:
    Container ID:   containerd://c544f832e260640b3b0b86355764d755292f909d476c45087697de487643fb87
    Image:          postgres:latest
    Image ID:       docker.io/library/postgres@sha256:8d3be35b184e70d81e54cbcbd3df3c0b47f37d06482c0dd1c140db5dbcc6a808
    Port:           5432/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 06 Nov 2024 08:46:03 +0000
      Finished:     Wed, 06 Nov 2024 08:46:03 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  3
    Environment:
      POSTGRES_DB:        keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER:      postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/postgresql/data from postgres-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-ngd88 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  PodReadyToStartContainers   True 
  Initialized                 True 
  Ready                       False 
  ContainersReady             False 
  PodScheduled                True 
Volumes:
  postgres-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  postgres-keycloak-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-ngd88:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  68s                default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Normal   Scheduled         67s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/keycloak-deployment-85d769f687-rfqbq to i-0c69be53d4d6e8dfe.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulled            65s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "postgres:latest" in 729ms (729ms including waiting). Image size: 154600919 bytes.
  Normal   Pulled            63s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "postgres:latest" in 758ms (758ms including waiting). Image size: 154600919 bytes.
  Normal   Pulled            49s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "postgres:latest" in 746ms (746ms including waiting). Image size: 154600919 bytes.
  Normal   Pulling           22s (x4 over 66s)  kubelet            Pulling image "postgres:latest"
  Normal   Created           21s (x4 over 65s)  kubelet            Created container postgres
  Normal   Started           21s (x4 over 65s)  kubelet            Started container postgres
  Normal   Pulled            21s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "postgres:latest" in 738ms (738ms including waiting). Image size: 154600919 bytes.
  Warning  BackOff           7s (x6 over 63s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container postgres in pod keycloak-deployment-85d769f687-rfqbq_default(cc5f184b-590f-418b-b752-94e742d565ce)


There's no description of the error, post the output of kubectl logs -l app=postgres to your question.

I don't know if this is due to the fact that it crashes immediately, but if I start it without storage I can access the logs, with the storage it just gives me a permission error: chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted
